# in laravel how to display image in home.blade.php or any page, from out side of laravel project (out side of root folder)

Tags: laravel

**in laravel (localhost and online hosting )how to display image in home.blade.php or any page, from out side of laravel project (out side of root folder)**

**i tried this two code but not work.**

```
 <div><img src="file:///C:/USER/User_Profile_Image/{{ Auth::user()->image }}" alt="profile"/></div>


   <div><img src="file:///C:/USER/User_Profile_Image/default.jpeg" alt="profile"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you an answer I just wanted to mention, I wouldnt suggest accessing anything outside of your project directory, this can cause many problems when it comes to relocation of the project or if a file structure changes.

### Possible Solution (Not Recommended)

If you had reasoning to have to access something outside of the laravel directory you can just use the '..' which means going into the parent folder.

#### Example

```
<img src="../../../User_Profile_Image/default.jpeg" alt="profile"/>
```

Other than that you could look into some straight PHP things around the documentation.

### Alternatives ()

If you are trying to store and access images in a public place you can use the public folder in laravel. Everything in this folder can be accessed by the public and is made to store publicly accessible things in such as profile pictures.

#### Public Example

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);
```

```
<img src="/file.jpg" alt="profile"/>
```

Hope this answered your question, good luck!

Comment: Not working i tried this ( <img src="../../../User_Profile_Image/default.jpeg" alt="profile"/> ) help me